# How to achieve this responsive CSS layout?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code I wrote. The layout should be responsive.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
   <title></title>
         <style type="text/css">
          .box {
               border: 1px solid black;
               }
         </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="height: 600px;">
    <div class="box" style="width: 30%; height: 70%; float: left"></div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 69%; height: 20%; float: left;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 15%; height: 50%; float: left;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 54%; height: 10%; float: left;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 54%; height: 70%; float: left;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 45%; height: 30%; float: left;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: `<div class="box" style="width: 70%; height: 20%; float: left;"></div>`
Make 70%

Comment: The bottom 30 x 45 block is coming below. The pic is what i want to achieve.

Comment: Have you tried below answer ?

Comment: Create fiddle with all css and html

Comment: I assume you dont really want the border. But to make your layout work with it try adding box-sizing:border-box

Comment: Even on old questions, please do not attempt to delete any part of them once you have received the help you want. They are kept in order to help other readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning:

```
<div style="height: 600px; position: relative;">
    <div class="box" style="width: 30%; height: 70%; top: 0%; left: 0%;">1</div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 70%; height: 20%; top: 0%; left: 30%;">2</div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 15%; height: 50%; top: 20%; left: 30%;">3</div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 55%; height: 10%; top: 20%; left: 45%;">4</div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 55%; height: 70%; top: 30%; left: 45%;">5</div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 45%; height: 30%; top: 70%; left: 0%;">6</div>
</div>

.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hn5s6/